# Getting error=206 debugging CordApp-Tutorial in Windows

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, corda

I'm getting the following error debugging the CordApp-Tutorial on Windows:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

I've already tried shortened the path, without success. Did someone get this error?

PS. This error only happens on release-M13, as the Main class changed from main to test module.

Comment: What Run/debug configuration is used? IntelliJ IDEA should suggest you to enabled dynamic classpath option. Google for details.

Comment: How did you try shortening the path? Have you tried installing the JDK at the root of the drive (e.g. at c:\jdk-1.8.0_131), and pointing IntelliJ at that?

Comment: Hi guys, I've just shortened the path even more (installed JDK in c:\dev\) and now it's ok. Thanks.

Comment: @joel you should cut/paste your comment as an answer such that Alexandre can credit you with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by shortening the path by installing the JDK at the root of the drive (e.g. at c:\jdk-1.8.0_131), and pointing IntelliJ at that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle, you can also install [this plugin](https://github.com/viswaramamoorthy/gradle-util-plugins)

Quote below from their documentation

> When classpath for a Gradle JavaExec task is long, Windows command executions give error because of limitation to command line length greater than 32K.

With a number of classpath dependencies in a large project, typically JavaExec Gradle task fails with error "The filename or extension is too long" and this would be a stopping error. To solve this issue, use ManifestClasspath plugin.

ManifestClasspath plugin creates a manifest jar for jar files in the classpath of JavaExec task and sets the classpath with manifest jar.